# WCF service deployed in IIS is not up

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have built a WCF service, by creating a WCF service library project and hosting that service library project in a WCF Service website(While creating a new application to the solution, choose WCF service), by adding the service library project as the reference.

Now, I have tested the WCF service, by running the application in which the service is being hosted. So, WCF test client pop-up came in, and have enjoyed invoking the service contract methods of the WCF service.

So, I chose to deploy the application in IIS and make it consumable for other client applications. For the same, I published the application and deployed the same folder in iis.

Now, when I tried browsing the service, the service loads for lifetime. I don't see the service up.

My iis deployment structure is,

[image: WCFServiceSample is my service deployment]

Please guide me in making the service ready for consumption.

Thanks
Manikandan J

Comment: Try deploying it as an application under the Default Website, not a new web site.

Comment: could be a port 80 problem conflicting with existing page (DefaultWebSite). What happen if you disable DefaultWebSite and try to start your Service Website

Comment: The port number I use is 7741. Let me try deploy under default website.